# vba column address from column number

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function, worksheet, text-extraction

I have a column number , say `columnNumber = 4` . I need the used range of this column. I know how to find the last used row, and I could convert the column number to a column number like so

```
ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, ColumnNumber).Address, "$")(1)
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, ColumnLetter).End(xlUp).Row
```

and then build an address like so

```
rngaddy = ColumnLetter & "1:" & ColumnLetter & LastRow
```

and finally do

```
Range(rngaddy)
```

But is there an easier way to find the complete used range of a column given it's number ?

Comment: You can use `Range.Cells(rownumber, colnumber)` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   Dim rngaddy As Range
    With Sheet1
        Set rngaddy = .Range(.Cells(1, 4), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp))
    End With
```

and if, for some reason, you want to see the address in `A1` notation, merely:

```
debug.print rngaddy.address
```

Note that in doing it this way, `rngaddy` is, itself, the range object and not a string. So no need to do `Range(rngaddy)`

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was doing around about way.

Answer (score 1):

You could return the last populated cell is in columns # `col` with this:

```
MsgBox Cells(sht.Rows.Count,col).End(xlUp).Address
```

If you want to return the first populated cell as well, you could use:

```
MsgBox IIf(IsEmpty(Cells(1,col)),Cells(1,col).End(xlDown),Cells(1,col)).Address
```

Therefore this would return only the "used" range of Column #4 (D):

```
Sub Example_GetUsedRangeOfColumn()
   Const col = 4
   Dim sht As Worksheet
   Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")
   MsgBox Range(IIf(IsEmpty(Cells(1, col)), Cells(1, col).End(xlDown), _
       Cells(1, col)), Cells(sht.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp)).Address
End Sub
```

---

- So with this example:

  [image: img]  ...the above procedure would return:  [image] .

Answer (score 1):

My preferred method is to use ListObjects aka Excel Tables to hold any input data whenever I possibly can. ListObjects are named ranges that Excel automatically maintains on your behalf, and because they grow automatically when new data is added, they give you a very robust way of referencing ranges in Excel from VBA, that is more immune to users doing things that might otherwise break code reliant on the .End(xlUp) approach.

[image]

```
? Range("MyTable").ListObject.ListColumns("Column 1").DataBodyRange.Address
$A$3:$A$7
```

Often I'll give the column concerned a named range of its own, in case the user (or a developer) later wants to change the Table column name, and use that name in my code instead.

[image]

```
? Range("FirstColumn").Address
$A$3:$A$7
```

If somebody (perhaps me) adds rows/columns above/left of the range of interest or shuffles the order of Table columns around, or changes the name of a column, the code still references the intended range and doesn't need to be changed.

[image]

```
? Range("FirstColumn").Address
$C$4:$C$8
? Range(Range("FirstColumn").Address & ":" &  Range("FirstColumn").EntireColumn.cells(1).address).Address
$C$1:$C$8
```

Granted, that method of getting the range from the top cell (which may be above the ListObject) to the bottom of the column concerned is kinda long, but once you start using ListObjects more in your code you normally don't care what is above or below them...you just want the goods held inside.

I haven't used .End(xlUp) in years, other than to find where my data ends should I be in the process of turning it into a ListObject. But I'm a ListObject evangelist...your mileage may vary :-)

Comment: Thanks, I will keep this in mind, but I usually end up pivoting the data , and tables and pivots don't play well together ( if I remember correctly, something about grouping dates ???)

Comment: Every pivot table I ever make has a Table as a data source. They are perfect for Pivots because they are dynamic named ranges meaning you never have to use the Change Data Source button ever again.

Comment: I've never heard about any issues that Tables cause PivotTables. Date grouping issues will be down to the PivotTable side of the equation. Some time back, you couldn't group dates for PowerPivot tables but that's been fixed. And you can't group dates if one of the items is a non-date (e.g. blank) but that's not specific to Pivots based on Tables.

Answer (score 1):

to get the *real* `UsedRange` of a columns you could use:

```
With Columns(columnNumber).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Set rngaddy = .Parent.Range(.Areas(1), .Areas(.Areas.Count))
End With
```

where `rngaddy` is a `Range` object

of course what above would fail if the column has no "constant" cells, then you may want to add some error trapping or entry check (e.g. `If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(columnNumber)) = 0 Then Exit Sub`

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Const columnNumber As Long = 4
    Dim rngaddy As Range
    Set rngaddy = Intersect(Columns(2), ActiveSheet.UsedRange): Debug.Print rngaddy.Address
End Sub
```